# Audio processing from Arduino

Tags: arduino, audio, avr, output, input

The project is to design a device with multiple audio inputs and multiple audio outputs. The device should be capable to map input and output audio channels. Output almost same as the input. At what point should I start the project?

Comment: Start the project with a full requirements specification document. Get it approved by whoever is project manager or customer. Then set into stone a project plan that incorporates team members. Review it and make changes as necessary to accommodate the various skills of the people involved. Of course this means that you know the various project stages <-- this ought to and can take a good deal of effort. Planning and target requirements are vital.

Comment: Is this really "processing", or is it about "routiing"?

Comment: Explain the requirements and what kind of audio, you must mean electrical signals? Why is Arduino a requirement, or what do you mean by Arduino? The MCU board, the IDE, or what?

Comment: @ScottSeidman sorry. it is not processing. it should be routing

Comment: @Justme just audio input from 3.5mm jack. my plan is to do routing with arduino uno. can you please help me.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the reply. this is diy project to do this by myself.

Comment: @kachaya How many inputs? How many outputs? Is mapping one input to one output enough? Mapping one input to multiple ouputs? Mapping multiple inputs to one output? What would an Arduino do in the circuit?

Comment: Do you imagine all the audio being processed by the Arduino or could the processor just enable and disable analog circuity? Arduinos are not very fast.

Comment: Pick out the chip you're going to use for the switch, then pick out whatever Arduino you want to use to do the switching.

Comment: Before picking the switch chip to use, first know what flavours of audio on 3.5mm plugs you want to route, is it mic levels, do you need mic support, is it low impedace headphone levels, or just high impedace line level. Then determine if you want hifi quality or is whatever quality enough. What are typical sources and loads determine the switch type. You may want audio buffers depending on what you expect the circuit to do.

Comment: what do you mean by "start the project"? start system design? draw up a project plan? do requirements gathering? plan a budget? do detailed design?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've now specified that you're interested in routing, and not processing, I suppose the first thing to take on is the overall method you're going to use.

I suppose there are two real choices:

1. You can sample the audio and send it to wherever you need it to go
2. You can employ some sort of switching matrix, and use your Arduino to control the switches.

Personally, if you're talking about using something like an Arduino Uno, I recommend leaning toward choice 2.

To do that, I recommend looking into analog switch integrated circuits suitable for audio, and using them to implement whatever sort of switching matrix you need.  I'm tempted to recommend that at least initially, you test whatever you come up with using analog SPST switches to control the IC switches, just removing any issues of programming until you know exactly the matrix you're designing.